# Dynamic lazy initialization for val in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, lazy-initialization

I understand there are two ways for lazy initialization in kotlin. first by `lateinit` which is dynamic but it is only for `var`. second, by `lazy` delegate which is for `val` but it is **static**, which means it can't be initialized at runtime.
I was wondering is there a way to have lazy dynamic initialization for immutable properties(`val`)????

property delegation also works like `lazy` and even if we define a custom delegate, its always static initialization. (to my knowledge)

is there a workaround for this? could it be implemented somehow?
so what I wish for, is something like `lateinit val`, shown in below code:

```
class MyClass: SomeCallback {
    
    private lateinit val myData: String
    
    override fun onStatusChanged(status: Status, data: String) {
        if(status == Status.DataConfirmed ) {
            myData = data
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You mean you want a property that throws an error if accessed before it's set, but only allows you to set it once? Only a `var` can be set.

Comment: if you want a static val, put your declaration inside a companion object or an Object class

Comment: @Tenfour04 yes.

Comment: You could write a property delegate that throws if its setter is called more than once. There's no way to avoid making it a `var` if you want to be able to set it after class initialization.

Comment: @zuko I don't understand, it gives the property must be initialized error

Comment: @Tenfour why is that? is it because of jvm? or they haven't implemented that feature?

Comment: You can't set something without a setter. A `val` by definition doesn't have a setter.

Comment: yes I get it, but I don't wanna set it, I want to initialize it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I can come up with is a read-write property delegate that throws if you access it before setting it, or if you set it multiple times. Kotlin doesn't let you `lateinit` a `val`. This is likely because it would be nonsensical to call a setter for a property that doesn't have one. I doubt they want to introduce the can of worms it would be to directly set the value of a backing field from anywhere besides the initializer, because it would be ambiguous.

A delegate like this should be adequate. If it's not adequate to help you immediately fix the bug of calling the setter multiple times, I would say that's a code smell that the class is too complicated and needs to be broken up into smaller units.

```
class Once<T>: ReadWriteProperty<Any, T> {
    private object UNINITIALIZED
    private var _value: Any? = UNINITIALIZED

    override fun getValue(thisRef: Any, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        if (_value !== UNINITIALIZED) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return _value as T
        }
        throw UninitializedPropertyAccessException("Property [$property] was accessed before it was initialized.")
    }

    override fun setValue(thisRef: Any, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        if (_value === UNINITIALIZED) {
            _value = value
        } else {
            error("Cannot set property [$property] more than once.")
        }
    }
}
```